# Show that using induction example

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> Numbers $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ satisfy
>   $$a_i>0,\quad c_i>0,\quad b_i>a_i+c_i\,\,\,\text{for}\,\,\,i=1,2,\ldots,I-1$$
>   and
>   $$u_i=\frac{c_i}{b_i-a_iu_{i-1}},\,\,\,i=1,2,\ldots,I-1\,\,\,\text{with}\,\,\,u_0=0.$$

---

> Show by induction that $0<u_i<1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,I-1$

I have worked through the following:

**Take $i=1$:** $$u_1 = \frac{c_1}{b_1 - a_1u_0} = \frac{c_1}{b_1}<\frac{c_1}{a_1+c_1}<1\,\,\text{ since $a_i>0$}.$$
A fraction of two positive numbers will always be greater than zero so
$$0<u_1<1\,\,\text{ holds for $i=1$ case.}$$
**Take $i=k$:** Assume that $$0<u_k = \frac{c_k}{b_k - a_ku_{k-1}}<1\,\,\text{ is true.}$$
**Take $i=k+1$:** $$0<u_k = \frac{c_{k+1}}{b_{k+1} - a_{k+1}u_{k}}< \frac{c_{k+1}}{a_{k+1} + c_{k+1} - a_{k+1}u_{k}} = u_k = \frac{c_{k+1}}{a_{k+1}(1 - u_k) + c_{k+1}}$$
Now take the extreme cases:
$$\LARGE 0<u_{k+1}=\begin{align*}
\left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
    \frac{c_{k+1}}{c_{k+1}} &\le 1\,\,\text{ if }\,\,u_k = 1 \\
    \frac{c_{k+1}}{a_{k+1} + c_{k+1}} &< 1\,\,\text{ if }\,\,u_k = 0 \\
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}$$
So, since $0<u_k<1$ that then means that $u_{k+1}$ is strictly less that $1$ thus
$$0<u_{k+1}<1\quad\text{QED.}$$

---

So is what I have done show the desired result properly? Can someone who is good at induction look this over for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage $k \rightarrow k+1$ is not very clear. Here is a better way to formulate it :

Suppose that $0 < u_k < 1$. Then, as $a_{k+1} > 0$, $$0 < a_{k+1} u_k < a_{k+1}$$ so $$b_{k+1} - a_{k+1} < b_{k+1} - a_{k+1}u_k < b_{k+1}$$
 Moreover, $b_{k+1} - a_{k+1} > c_{k+1}$ so $$c_{k+1} < b_{k+1} - a_{k+1}u_k < b_{k+1}$$
 You get finally, as $c_{k+1} > 0$
$$\frac{c_{k+1}}{b_{k+1}} < \frac{c_{k+1}}{b_{k+1} - a_{k+1}u_k} < \frac{c_{k+1}}{c_{k+1}}$$

so you have
$$0 < u_{k+1} < 1$$